# Solving or approximating integral of $e^{-u^2}$ divided by quadratic function

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to solve or approximate the following type of integrals:
$$\int_a^b \frac{\beta^2}{\beta^2 - c} e^{-u^2} du$$
or
$$\int_a^b \frac{c}{\beta^2 - c} e^{-u^2} du,$$
with $\beta = u \sqrt{2} \sigma + \mu$.

The limits are $a = -8.5$ and $b$ varies from -0.62 to -2.2. Or $a$ varies from -0.5 to 3 and $b\to\infty$.

The other values are constant:

$c = 0.31$

$\sigma = 0.05$

$\mu = 1.7$

This integral is for finding a probability distribution from a product of distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)

I would like an approximate answer to see more clearly the effect of different parameters instead of having to compute the integral numerically each time.

Comment: If it can be factorised, the exponential integral will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the values that you are giving us, it seems that $\sigma \ll 1$. So you could try to use the approximation (expansion in $\mu\sigma \ll \mu^2 ,\mu^2 -c$)
$$
\int_a^b \frac{\beta^2}{\beta^2 -c} e^{-u^2}\,du \approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \mu^2}{2 (\mu^2 -c)} (\operatorname{erf}(b) -\operatorname{erf}(a)) +\frac{\sqrt 2 c\mu \sigma}{(\mu^2 - c)^2} (e^{-b^2} - e^{-a^2}) \,.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\int_a^b \frac{c}{\beta^2 -c} e^{-u^2}\,du \approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi} c}{2 (\mu^2 -c)} (\operatorname{erf}(b) -\operatorname{erf}(a)) +\frac{\sqrt 2 c \mu \sigma}{(\mu^2 - c)^2} (e^{-b^2} - e^{-a^2}) \,.
$$

By the way, if course you have to limit the boundaries of integration such that $\beta^2 \neq c$ nowhere in the region of integration.

Comment: That's seems like a good approximation; for the first integral, where is the second term coming from? Don't you get a constant times $e^{-u^2}$ for the integral?

Comment: @Alex: sorry for the late reply (and thanks for the approval). The formulas you simply get, by Taylor expanding (everything except for $exp(-u^2)$) in $u$ around $u=0$. In this way, you could easily produce more terms.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you could obtained a closed form expression for the antiderivative.

Using your notations,
$$I=\int \frac{e^{-u^2}}{\beta^2 - c} \, du=\frac{1}{2 \sigma ^2}\int \frac{e^{-u^2}}{u^2+\alpha u +\gamma }\,du$$ whith
$$\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{2} \mu }{\sigma }\qquad \text{and} \qquad \gamma=\frac{\mu ^2-c}{2 \sigma ^2}$$ Using partial fraction
$$\frac 1{u^2+\alpha u +\gamma }=\frac 1{(u-a)(u-b)}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac 1{u-a} -\frac 1{u-b}\right)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the quadratic equation in $u$. So, we face two integrals
$$I_k=\int \frac{e^{-u^2}}{u-k} \, du$$ which do not seem to be known if $k\neq 0$.

If $k\ll 1$ (which is not the case at all with your data), we could approximate $I_k$ axpanding as a series around $k=0$ and write
$$I_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int \frac{e^{-u^2}}{u^{n+1}}  k^n\, du=-\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \Gamma \left(-\frac{n}{2},u^2\right)\, k^n$$

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer @Claude. Actually this answer also gave me a good approximation. What I was able to do is the following; one of the roots was small compared to the u integration range values, and the other large compared to the values, so the partial fraction could be approximated closely with $\frac{1}{a-b} ( \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{b} )$